# Finding values from an array that doesnt match with cookie

Tags: php, mysql

OK, so within the database each AD has its own ID. When a user has seen the Ad I'll set a cookie with ID of the ad.

Problem I have is, when they come back, I don't want the to see the same ad. Here's what I have so far.

```
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM running_ads";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$array = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $array[] = $row;
}

$i = 0;

While($array[$i]['invoice_id'] == $_COOKIE) {

$i = $i +1;

}


 $actual_id = $array[$i]['invoice_id'];
```

I've tried to increase the row number so it will go down the database until it gets to one where the Invoice_id is not he same as the cookie.

When I print out `$actual_id` it just prints the top one, regardless of the fact I have that set as a cookie.

This may be simple for someone but i seem to have just hit a wall.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you forget to set the cookie key?

Comment: I have added this like anwerjunaid said, however it still just displays the first once in the database.

Answer (score 1):

**$_COOKIE** is array , you should supply the key for **$_COOKIE** like

```
While($array[$i]['invoice_id'] == $_COOKIE['invoice_id'])
```

use your cookie name if not invoice_id.